Cascaded Half bridge and H bridge
I am currently researching cascade inverters. The upper bridge is a half bridge, and the lower bridge is a full bridge. The second picture shows the waveform. The first row of the second picture shows the half bridge output, the second row shows the full bridge output, and the third row shows all outputs. This is not a five-level circuit. There should be something wrong with the upper bridge. I use the level-shift control method. Please help me see how to output correctly.



This is my gate driver for the top half of the bridge. The bottom bridge is wrong.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am using level-shift control, and the upper bridge is a half-bridge. The waveform of the half-bridge is not three-level. Theoretically, it is the same three-level as the full-bridge. After cascading, it is 5-level. Now the result is wrong. I don't know if it is the cascade, the connection error or what.

@YiLuo - Hi, You posted an "answer" but it was actually more details which should be in the question, so I moved it into the question as an update. || Please see the site rules in the [tour] & [help] as Stack Exchange has different rules & etiquette to forums. Only answers to the original question should be written in the input box at the bottom of the page labeled "Your Answer". Since you asked the question, the only time you should use that input box is if you are writing a new, novel, full & final solution to your own question, which allows the question to be considered closed. TY
